# VS2015 and Xamarin and Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

i want to **integrate Google Maps with Xamarin using VS2015** can anybody suggest me link or the Step by Step guide to integrate **Google Maps, Xamarin Using VS2015**.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/